# Am I responsible for a site's lack of ADA compliancy if I open their site up in an iframe on my site?

Tags: legal

To be more specific, Let's say I'm the band Coldplay. We have a buy tickets link. When clicked, Ticketmaster's page opens up in an iframe. For this example, Ticketmaster is not ADA compliant and screen readers can not function well on their site. Am I responsible for this? Am I less responsible if the link just takes the user off my site? Am I responsible just for selling tickets on Ticketmaster's site? Tia

Comment: In your example, is Ticketmaster hosted in a jurisdiction where the ADA is relevant?

Comment: Well, I assume it is. My site is and I got hit with a lawsuit. Several services that I had links to such as Linktree, a ticket service etc... were mentioned. I made a new fully compliant site but I'm wondering how much I'm responsible for content on their site. Also, if having the ticket site in an iframe makes me more responsible.

Comment: I think there are a lot of different factors at play here to determine who is/isn't responsible. It is probably safe to say that, even if you aren't, you will spend enough money in litigation to sink you to pass the buck off. My main question would be "Do you have a service agreement with the iframe company or do you not have a legal agreement with them?" If you are merely linking to them to "make it easier", then I would just link to it rather than iframe. This way it should pass all "blame" over the site rather than you embedding it in your owned page(s).